# Why does the password I set not work?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I tried connecting to my headless raspberry Pi 2w on my Lenovo Windows 11, however it is not recognizing the password that I set. I tried doing this over 5 times just in case I made any typos but I was getting the same errors.

I was at a lost so I redid everything on my mac and succeeded on my first attempt. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I read someone here that he was having a similar problem but he managed to solved it by connecting to a 2.4Ghz WIFI instead of 5 G. In my case I used the same network for Windows and Mac.

I rather use my Windows for this project, but am also interested in figuring out what was the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: "Does anyone know how to fix this problem?" What problem? You say "I redid everything … and succeeded on my first attempt"

Comment: I'm not sure how you were entering the password (a terminal session?) but the typical password entry problem I sometimes face is different keyboard layouts on different PCs (UK vs US layout, QWERTY vs. QWERTZ, or various national layouts) or a even a caps lock - maybe check that on your Windows machine?

Comment: You tried connecting using what? What errors did you get? What did you redo? How did you set the password?

Comment: @Milliways I succeeded with my Mac. It is on my Windows that the password I set was not working. I did not have the same problem on my Mac. A search online revealed others had similar problems (some with different causes). I can now use my Mac, but I am just curious about what was causing the error on my Windows in case I (or others) run into a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @StarCat I tried connecting to my home WiFi. There were no errors except the password I had set was not working. My keyboard is not the problem either.